# SQL database copied and updated

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a main system that I use to add records to and run multiple routines on an SQL database using MS Access.  Some routines take days to run.

I want to build a second PC where I can hopefully easily update its copy of the database and then run the long routines on while continuing to keep up the day-to-day activities on the main system.

How easy (or feasible) is it to take a copy of a sql database from one computer and update it on another?

Comment: What is an *SQL database*? Did you mean SQL Server Database? Oracle Database? SQLite Database? SQL is a language that even MS Access uses.

Comment: @Parfait Since the question is tagged [tag:ms-access], I submit to you the asker is referring to an Access DB.

Comment: The answer to your question is don't have multiple copies of the DB. Replication (the standard name for what you're trying to do) is difficult to get right. It's much, much simpler and very likely more cost effective to use a truly a shared database. Storing the DB server side behind a fully fledged DBMS like SQL Server or PostgreSQL makes the task of sharing data between different systems much easier.

Comment: @jpmc26 ... MS Access as a GUI can connect to different backends (SQL Server, Postgres, SQLite) via linked tables/pass-through queries/VBA modules in addition to its own JET/ACE Engine. Hence we need clarity of *SQL Database*.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2014 for the database and using MS-Access as the means to add records etc. I understand the concept of setting up a server in order to "use a truly shared database."  But it is something I am nervous to try.  Also, since the long routines use the same tables and records as the daily routines, I worry that they'll be stepping on each other.  So I thought I'd research the idea of replicating the DB as a means to do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those processing times sound rather large. I would suggest that you consider building some server side routines that run on SQL server – they will run much faster, and more important reduce if not eliminate most network traffic. Keep in mind that working with lots of data using Access to SQL server can and will often run SLOWER than just using Access without SQL server.

As for moving the SQL database to another computer? The idea and concept is very much like moving a file like Access to another computer. You simply from SQL manager create backup file on the first computer. (it will be a single file – choose device, and then add a file location). You also find that such .bak files from SQL zip REALLY well, so if you using some kind of FTP or internet, then zip it file before you transmit it.

Regardless, you can even transfer that “bak” file with a jump drive or whatever. You then restore that database to the other computer – and you off to the races. (on the target computer, or your local computer, simply choose “restore” and restore the database from the “bak” file you transferred to the other computer running sql server. So the whole database with many tables etc. will be turned into a single file - much like access is.

So moving and making copies of a SQL database is a common task, and once you get the hang of this process, it not really much harder than moving an access file between computers.

I would however question why the process are taking so long – they may well be complex, but the use of store procedures and pass-through quires would substantial speed up your application as opposed to processing the data with a local client like Access + VBA. So try adopting more t-sql and store procedures – they will run “many” times faster – often 1 hour can be cut down to say 1 minute or less. So moving is easy, but you might eliminate the whole "day" of time down to a few minutes of time if you can run the processing routines server side as opposed to client side of which will occur when using Access as the client. (the access client can most certainly send or call t-sql routines that run server side - but the main trick here is to get those processing routines running server side).

Comment: Thanks, EVERYBODY, for your help and suggestions!  I really really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used ms access it was just a file like an excel file which you could simply copy to the other machine and do whatever you want with.

If you are fairly comfortable with sql/administration, and only need a one-way copy (main system to second PC) then you could migrate ms access to mysql:
http://www.kitebird.com/articles/access-migrate.html
(Telling Microsoft Access to Export Its Own Tables)

This process should be fairly easy to automate if you need to do this regularly.